# SharePoint 2010 Webpart - Get Settings value / hash wit jQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I want to read the value or hash from the settings of a webpart. I have to use jQuery to get the value / hash.

Here is my option entry from the .cs file:

```
    [Category("Wiki-Inhaltsverzeichnis Einstellungen"),
    WebBrowsable,
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
    WebDisplayName("angezeigte Ebenen")]
    public NumberOfLayers layer
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

and my NumberOfLayers.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WikiTableOfContents.TableOfContentsWebPart
{
    public enum NumberOfLayers
    {
        I,
        II,
        III,
        IV
    }
}
```

How can I put the value chosen in the webpart settings into a jQuery variable? The setting is shown and saved properly in the webpart settings.

I really appreciate your help!

Thank you.

Niels

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.

I added in the .webpart file under :

```
   <property name="layer" type="WikiTableOfContents.TableOfContentsWebPart.TableOfContentsWebPart+NumberOfLayers, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$">IV</property>
```